# Delete background, change color of video

Tags: vegas-pro

Is it possible to take, for example, this video

and somehow make dr. Manhattan's skin yellow/white? instead of blue? Is it possible to take out his figure/delete the surroundings? If yes, then how?

Comment: Since there is *heavy animated glowing* around him going on, I don't think that this is possible (in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve cutting out the background is by using after effects and rotoscoping Dr. Manhattan out - there are many tutorials online on how to rotoscope. [Adobe After Effects CS5- Rotoscope with Rotobrush](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYgfDUnA1Ys)

Once you've done this, grade Dr. Manhattan to your liking by using a colour correction tool such as levels, and hue/saturation. You may have to rotoscope in/out the colours you want to keep.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use DaVinci Resolve.

First node: You can use a qualifier to get the basic outline of Dr. Manhattan (not the glow around him, but the darker blue parts).

Second node: You can feed one output from that first node through hue vs. hue to convert blue to yellow.

Third node: You can feed another output from the first node to a mask.

Fourth node: You can then then blur the mask (outside only, not inside and outside) and tint it to make your yellow glow.

Fifth node: you can use the mask of the 3rd node to select the output of the second node and composite that with the output of the fourth node to get a yellow body with a yellow glow, and no background.